# How I can refactor this code to execute method logViolation() only once and get all value of string variable (speedType) in single string

Tags: java

How I can refactor the code below to execute method `logViolation()` only once and get all values of string variable `speedType` in a single string?

```java
private void checkForViolation(
    final LineFeature feature, 
    final DirectionalVehicleTypeRestrictionCollection srSet,
    final Map<String, Collection<String>> setOfVehiclesWithMoreThanOneSpeedRestrictionType
) {
    for (final Entry<String, Collection<String>> entry : setOfVehiclesWithMoreThanOneSpeedRestrictionType.entrySet()) {
        final String speedType = entry.getKey();
        final Collection<String> value = entry.getValue();
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(value)) {
            final Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
            set.addAll(value);
            logViolation(feature, speedType, srSet.getDirection().getTypeShortName(), set);
        }
    }
}

private void logViolation(
    final LineFeature feature, final String speedRestrictionType, 
    final String direction, final Set<String> vehicleTypesSet
) {
    final ViolationVariableSpeedInfo viva = new ViolationVariableSpeedInfo(
        ViolationVariableKey.SPEED_INFO.getKey(),
        speedRestrictionType, vehicleTypesSet, direction
    );

    getRuleContext().logViolation(feature, viva);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all keys from the input map `setOfVehiclesWithMoreThanOneSpeedRestrictionType` need to be merged in a single string as well as all the values from this map should be merged in a single `TreeSet` and then logged, this may be implemented as simple as:

```java
private void checkForViolation(
    final LineFeature feature, 
    final DirectionalVehicleTypeRestrictionCollection srSet,
    final Map<String, Collection<String>> map
) {
    String speedType = String.join(", ", map.keySet());
    TreeSet<String> set = map.values().stream()
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));

    logViolation(feature, speedType, srSet.getDirection().getTypeShortName(), set);
}
```